# Railo 4/ Tomcat / IIS7.5 / Coldfusion / cffile upload of docx not working

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, iis-7.5, railo, cffile

I just moved a web application from a ColdFusion to Railo server and encountered a puzzling issue with the application's file upload functionality. Everything works fine for almost all files, but .docx files don't get uploaded. In Railo I see the error:

> form field [form.theformfieldname] is not a file field

I have registered the "docx" mimetype in IIS and Tomcat as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

I just did a small test and cfdumped the `#form#` twice. The first time with a .doc file, and the second time with a .docx file.

**Dump 1: .doc file**

```
Scope
docsbestand string  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\WEB-INF\railo\temp\tmp-321.upload
fieldnames string   jsoninput,docsbestand
jsoninput string    {"PRO":{"idaanvraag":"052300022920333" ,"bron":"Spontaan"},"apiklant":"demo","apikey":KL541231231}
```

**Dump 2: .docX file**

```
docsbestand
string  PK!0�(r�[Content_Types].xml �(��T�n�0�W�?D�V������[��0��z��l�I�Q�B� \"%���ك�ښl  �w%�=���^i7+���%�g&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S ����X��&��V$z�3��3෽���%p)O5�����5}�:�`�e�ۅ�V�DFK��)_:�K%�)�l��\�!��U�'�v�7�&j�X��*,��+W^.,�����W����k��D�ܚ��X�ݷ��>��N!��FZ�&0m��ly��)�q�9��d}��@��?Ĥ�����R��/��s���*&:t��g������ˉ�8Y�O�[�&V0}�X�?Ȼ���>�#��;�F�io.����PK!���N_rels/.rels �(����JA���a�}7� "���H�w"����w̤ھ�� �P�^����O֛���;�<�aYՠ؛`G�kxm��PY�[��g Gΰino�/<���<�1��ⳆA$>"f3��\�ȾT��I S����������W����Y ig�@��X6_�]7~ f��ˉ�ao�.b*lI�r�j)�,l0�%��b� 6�i���D�_���,  � ���|u�Z^t٢yǯ;!Y,}{�C��/h>��PK!ʡ��9`word/_rels/document.xml.rels �(����N�@��&�ٻl�ZMS�5����la�.�dw���I(4�x�B2�}?fvX�������`(&<�Ĥ%��_o��Ha��AEN����;hE�+��y�.Q���%T���;���".m.k��Tr>�-�z����ۤ����VxqSs���&���M���B�t@�_��S�(��3����D n ��m)�k0�0���Q�y�}�z,>�2��,ϡ'8Jc�)!2�����(�A�O Q�ɶ��]߉J���2��ç�Я��z3)/�ˁ������MI� ۏ���]���!���PK!q�� �word/document.xml�]Ks�H�o����c~B���s�;�nm�F�@��B0�_��B�� !�6�­9�i    J��_>+��巿&�6�o:�Y����4nôGg�Ǉ��iM�f�rl~V{�~�����e�1��t��@�!l�3��� p;��?� ����ps�x�?�Qc¼�[8�fߴ������Z4�sV�zv'�>1��;��q�Cs���/�s���H���48�?6]_�6y�h��X2���lb����<O3<6yL��s�3\�p߇�W�����gG�C,���LAɄ��rDǊ����5�n�P���\tK}�x�OW�w�Fﬦ���Q�]��Aк~z}t�����M�`����K���~x�Ǎc>���i���ؙ0u|n����_�n��O�֌Y�-ǵ��%�ֈ�n�@�B���c(��k� <SNIP>

string  jsoninput,docsbestand
jsoninput string {"PRO":{"idaanvraag":"052300022920333" ,"bron":"Spontaan"},"apiklant":"demo","apikey":KL541231231}
```

Somehow the file is not uploaded to the tmp-directory but read/parsed/whatever. And of course the cffile upload wont work in those cases.

What could be causing this?

thanks!
Bart

Comment: a workaround i implemented is renaming the file before upload (to .doc), passing an extra parameter with the real extension (in this case .docx, but maybe the same problem exists for other filetypes aswell later) and then renaming it again after the succesfull upload. But this also means that customers will have to implement this workaround on their sides...certainly not ideal!

Comment: Have you looked around with things related to adding handled MIME types?

Comment: yes - i looked, added, changed the mimetypes - but no effect...